# how to disable automatic pop up of keyboard while exiting text

Tags: keyboard, 5.1-lollipop, popup

I have android 5.1 on my samsung mobile. I have Ms word app on it. When i tap anywhere in any opened word document, automatic android keyboard pops up. This is very annoying during reading the document. I have to press back button again and again in order to make it disappear. I have checked in the settings of android in order to disable this auto pop up feature but i could not find any.

Can anybody tell me how to disable this auto pop up of android keyboard?

Comment: The keyboard pops up automatically when a textbox/edit text field is selected. I don't think there is a way to disable it... And you are reading in edit mode,  you have to read the document in read-only.

Comment: If you go to the length of getting a hard keyboard (e.g. bluetooth one), then that can disable the soft keyboard but perhaps a bit of an extreme. I haven't tried this but perhaps voice typing may do the same (last thing I want personally).